# Typescript Abstract Function Causes Import.default not assignable Error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this setup:

```
class MustHave
{
  clone<T> : T;
}

class Implementation implements MustHave
{
  clone<Implementation>() : Implementation
  {
    ..
  }
}
```

This causes Type 'import(...).default' is not assignable to type Implementation

Implementation could not ber instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to <import.default statement from above>.

I'm wondering why it doesn't work, considering I use a generic to specify the return type and then use it in the function header.

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (this is a link to your code in a web IDE)](https://tsplay.dev/wXkLDW), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing (with no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values). This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: Generic functions and methods have type parameters which are specified by the *caller* and not the *implementation*.  Imagine writing a function of type `(x: number) => void`; the implementation cannot choose `x`; it must accept any `x` the caller passes in.  Similarly, a function of type `<T>() => void`, the implementation cannot choose `T`, it must accept any `T` the caller specifies.   I'd explain more, but I'd really like to see a more well-posed code example before I post an answer.  Good luck!